# How to reduce the size of the .wav file exported from Pydub

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, pydub

When I do a conversion using ffmpeg, I am able to convert a 3.5MB mp3 file into an ~3.5MB wav file (using `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 8000 output.wav`).
When I use pydub however with the below code

```
s1 = AudioSegment.from_file("input.mp3", format="mp3")
o1 = s1.export("output.wav",format="wav", parameters=["-acodec","pcm_s16le","-ac","1","-ar","8000"])
```

the exported wav file is 34.5MB.
How can I get pydub to behave as expected?

Comment: If you are converting a 3.5MB `mp3` into a 3.5MB `wav`, something has gone wrong somewhere. The entire point of `mp3` is to compress the raw samples from a `wav` file.

Comment: It seems like you are massively down-sampling the `wav`, your `wav` file has nowhere near the same audio quality as the `mp3`, is this intentional? Beware that byte for byte `mp3` and `wav` are very different...

Comment: @TomWyllie yes, it's intentional to down-sample the output file. I intend to use the audio file with freeswitch.
Due to storage and bandwidth restriction, I cannot have each file being that big

Comment: If it's possible in your use case, gzipping the wav file after you export will reduce the size considerably

Comment: although I could not tell from inspecting the code, I don't think pydub supports what I was trying to do. I went ahead and wrote me a helper function to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
s1.export("output.mp3", format='mp3', parameters=["-ac","2","-ar","8000"])
```

The line of code managed to reduce my audio size by half its previous size. Hope this is helpful to someone

Comment: Works good, but the quality loose is very significant.